# How to process "data" part of GCP PubSub message into a HashMap?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, subscriber

I'm getting pubsub message as below :

```
{
  "data": {
    "systemId": "system-1",
    "userId": "userId-1",
    "departmentId": "090",
    "enrolmentDateTime": "2022-08-19T15:44:29.080Z",
    "event_type": "REGISTRATION"
  }
}
```

I want to further process this message in my springboot application based on the "event_type".
How can I just fetch "event_type" from this message and use it for comparison?
Any suggestions?

For eg I want to have processing like this :

`if(event_type.equals("REGISTRATION")) { registrationHandler.handle(message); else { }`

I have tried converting a PubSubMessage into string and then further map it to HashMap using ObjectMapper, but that gives me "data" as key and rest of the json part as a value.

```
public void process(final PubsubMessage message) throws ConsumerException {
    String data = message.getData().toStringUtf8();

    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        HashMap<String, String> dataMap = mapper.readValue(data, HashMap.class);
        } ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Map`, you can use a typed object, example :

`PubSubData.java` file :

```java
public class PubSubData {
    private String systemId;
    private String userId;
    private String departmentId;
    private String enrolmentDateTime;
    private String event_type;

    public PubSubData() {
    }

    public String getSystemId() {
        return systemId;
    }

    public void setSystemId(String systemId) {
        this.systemId = systemId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(String departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public String getEnrolmentDateTime() {
        return enrolmentDateTime;
    }

    public void setEnrolmentDateTime(String enrolmentDateTime) {
        this.enrolmentDateTime = enrolmentDateTime;
    }

    public String getEvent_type() {
        return event_type;
    }

    public void setEvent_type(String event_type) {
        this.event_type = event_type;
    }
}
```

`PubSubResult.java` file :

```java
public class PubSubResult {
    private PubSubData data;

    public PubSubResult() {
    }

    public PubSubData getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(PubSubData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Example of an unit test that deserializes data from `PubsubMessage` to the `PubSubResult` object :

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER;

    static {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);

        OBJECT_MAPPER = mapper;
    }


    @Test
    public void testDeserializePubSubData() {
        final String data = "{\n" +
                "  \"data\": {\n" +
                "    \"systemId\": \"system-1\",\n" +
                "    \"userId\": \"userId-1\",\n" +
                "    \"departmentId\": \"090\",\n" +
                "    \"enrolmentDateTime\": \"2022-08-19T15:44:29.080Z\",\n" +
                "    \"event_type\": \"REGISTRATION\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        final PubsubMessage message = PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
                .setData(ByteString.copyFrom(data.getBytes()))
                .build();

        final String dataResult = message.getData().toStringUtf8();

        final PubSubResult resultData = deserialize(dataResult);
        
        // Access to the event type.
        final String eventType = resultData.getData().getEvent_type();
    }

    private PubSubResult deserialize(final String value) {
        try {
            return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(value, PubSubResult.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error !!", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You’re welcome, can you mark the answer as resolved please ?

Comment: @Namrata I don't understand, you are deleted your comment, have you solved your issue ?